# Angular routing transition jumps to top of leaving route

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-animations

I'm currently trying to implement some angular route transition, with the entering route transitioning from bottom to top covering the former router (former route isn't to be animated at all).

To do so, I tried the following:

```
import {animate, animateChild, group, query, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';

export const SLIDE_UP_ANIMATION = [
  query(':enter, :leave', [
    style({
      height: '100vh',
      position: 'fixed',
      width: '100%',
    })
  ]),
  query(':enter', [
    style({
      transform: 'translateY(100%)'
    })
  ]),
  group([
    query(':enter', [
      animate('400ms ease-out', style({
        transform: 'translateY(0%)'
      }))
    ])
  ]),
  query(':enter', animateChild())
];

export const PAGES_ANIMATION = trigger('routeAnimations', [
  transition(`* <=> *`, SLIDE_UP_ANIMATION)
]);
```

It kind of works, but **when scrolled, the leaving route jumps to the top again** on route change - I want it to stay as it is, even when scrolled. How to do so?